# How do I view compiler errors in a problems window in CLion?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clion

I'm switching my project to use the CLion IDE and I'm wondering how I can view the problem's window that shows errors and warnings in the problems tool window [described here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/problems-tool-window.html). The support page doesn't seem very helpful.

Some people have mentioned elsewhere that you can use Inspect Code, but this doesn't show the errors that the compiler gives

Answer (score 1):

If your are looking for what I believe, the "Build" tab of the "Messages" window will give you the information.

If it is not showing, you can display it through:
View->Tool Windows -> Messages

For me, it sometimes disappear... then I restore the default layout Windows->Restore Default layout.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIS, Problems window doesn't have the default hotkey or menu item.

What you can do is go to Settings - Keymap - search for "Problems", and assign a hotkey, or customize toolbar or menu to include Problems tool window.

What's interesting is that it's not found by Problems in Actions window (Ctrl-Cmd-A or Shift-Cmd-A). It's worth reporting at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/